# How to write this type of format in latex

Tags: bibtex

How to align a title on the left side like given in this figure below written blue letters [image]

with code

```
\usepackage{titling} 
\title{\begin{flushleft} Communication \\ channels on “Experimental Validation of a Frequency-Selective Surface-Loaded Hybrid Metamaterial Absorber with Wide Bandwidth” \end{flushleft}} 

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Sudhir K. Sahoo} 
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Electrical Sciences} \\ 
\textit{Indian Institute of Technology Bhubaneswar}\\ 
Argul, Khordha, India \\ 
Email: sudhirrt10@gmail.com}
```

and also how to write the references in this format given figure below.[image]

Like after first sentences of a reference the next line shifted to right side with some space.

Code:

```
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{thebiblography} 
\bibitem{ILaSa:2008} mLandy N I, Sajuyigbe S, Mock J J, Smith D R, Padilla W J, (2008), “Perfect metamaterial absorber,” {\em Phys. Rev. Lett.}, vol. 100, p. 207402, doi: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.207402. 
\bibitem{ShaKh:2019}  Sharma A, Khanna R, Panwar R, (2019), “Experimental Validation of a Frequency-Selective Surface-Loaded Hybrid Metamaterial Absorber With Wide Bandwidth,” {\em IEEE Magn. Lett.}, vol. 10, doi: 10.1109/LMAG.2019.2898612. 
\end{thebibilography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `titling` package  defines tools to customise the `\maketitle` command. As to the bibliography, you can customise it through `biblatex`.

Comment: @Bernard Can you please give the code ... Actually I am not getting...

Comment: Could you please a minimal (complete) code with what you tried, so I don't start from scratch?